# \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list undefined control sequence in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I've tried to write a very simple Rmarkdown file to render as pdf, but got an error for an *undefined control sequence*.

The file:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "3/2/2020"
output: pdf_document
---

# whatever
fskjflsjflkj
```

saved as test.Rmd and knit (with the button) produces the following output in the R markdown console:

```
processing file: test.Rmd
output file: test.knit.md

! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

The following is the relevant `test.log` part:

```
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Old fixltx2e package on input line 53.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+lmr on input line 11
2.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list
```

It doesn't matter if I try to compile it with `pdflatex`, `lualatex` or `xelatex` the error is the same.

I'm working on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with everything updated and upgraded (`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` as root) and after running `tlmgr update --self --all`.

How can I get Rmarkdown to knit to pdf again?

Comment: Try to use `fmtutil-sys --all` to rebuilt the format files using those new sources (updated with tlmgr).

Comment: It worked wonderful, @J_F If you want to provide it as an answer, I'll be glad to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

to rebuilt the format files using those new sources (updated with tlmgr).

Comment: I have this same problem. How do I solve this on windows? I am using MiKTeX