# debugging rmarkdown error 'tlmgr' not found

Tags: r, r-markdown, tinytex

I'm trying to knit to PDF using an .rmd file. It failed and suggested I look:

> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.

The second step is to run `tinytex::tlmgr_update()`, however this returns:

> tlmgr update --all --self
>
> Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : '"tlmgr"' not found

How should I proceed?

Comment: What´s your OS? I´ve once given an answer here, perhaps it will also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60489469/xdef-fontencloadlist-fontencloadlist-undefined-control-sequence-in-rmark/60493558#60493558

Answer (score 3):

I would try running:

```r
tinytex:: install_tinytex()
```

then try running:

```r
update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `tinytex:::install_prebuilt()`. I found this solution that worked for me at https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-tinytex/129302